# Socket creation times out

Tags: java, sockets

I'm working on an assignment for my Distributed Computing course, which deals with basic sockets and I'm having a bit of a problem. My code executes and runs properly via SSH on university computers but from my laptop it doesn't.

I have a server java file that is running on a university computer via SSH. If I start another SSH session and run my code from that computer everything runs smoothly. However, if I execute that code off of my local machine I get a Socket Timed Out error.

Here's the code for the Client file, which throws the error:

```
try {
    addr = InetAddress.getByName("___IP_Here____");
    sock = new Socket(addr,3165);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Creating Socket failed.");
    System.out.println(e);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Here's the Server code for creating the server:

```
try {
    addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    sock = new ServerSocket(3165,3,addr);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Creating ServerSocket failed.");
    System.out.println(e);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

I thought that it might be a problem with the Firewall and I added exceptions to allow Java in both inbound and outbound. Does anyone have an idea of what could possibly be wrong?

EDIT: The server socket has a timeout of 0, which is infinity.
http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#getSoTimeout()

EDIT: This is actually a university security issue.

Comment: You don't want to specify an address for a `ServerSocket`, unless you have a good reason. The default is "all addresses".

Comment: I removed setting the IP address. Didn't change anything.

Comment: I agree and disagree with the comment. Binding the server to an IP will ensure you are not using distrusted networks and only your machine will be able to access while developing. Doing otherwise for an application that is supposed to work only on localhost and server local programs is a security problem. OBS, large campus networks are always dangerous   places =).

Comment: @user123345 That would qualify as a good reason. If you don't have that reason, or another good one, don't do it. There's nothing in this question about the software only being intended to work on the localhost.

Comment: Sorry to disagree (partially as noticed). However I do think I have to be the most specific I can whenever building something - regardless of the application. Moreover, my comment was not just about functionality. There are lots of security problems that can be avoided by doing so. Thus, as a security focused developer, I cannot say you should do this, but I see your point, doing so would complicate the program and require configuration for deploying.. well, this is just a comment.. I am not saying he has to do like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firewall might be your problem. Allowing java might be not enough, check for ports and rules with higher priority. If you are in a safe environment, or disconnected you might try to turn it off to confirm if it is the firewall or not. BTW, close your resources or consider using try-with-resources instead of simple try and catch, this other thing to look for, try to kill your process and check if you can connect.

Comment: I just tried disabling the firewall and testing, I still for a connection timed out error.

Comment: did you test the other issue?

Comment: Yes, in the firewall the Java rules allow any IP address' and ports.

Comment: the other one, your code might be leaking resources as you are not closing the connections.

Comment: I'll update the code and try that. Are you saying to do try-with-resources in the Server?

Comment: Ideally you should put on both of them. Kill your process before testing, they might still be using them. if is a Linux machine, it should be easy to see if there is ports been used, nmap should help. BTW, if this was the problem along with a firewall problem, your previous test was invalid and you should test the firewall again.

Comment: Other issue, your serversocket is not doing anything.
Consider looking at these necessary steps, is really short I promise:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: I tried using try-with-resources on both, didn't work. Tried it along side with disabling the firewall, also did not work.

Comment: @immibis might be right, it makes sense if you are biding to other address that is not the localhost.

Comment: try being specific like 127.0.0.x on both sides.

Comment: The problem is the Server is on another computer not on the local machine. And I'm running the client off of another machine.

Comment: well, I am still suspicious about the server not doing anything, not even accepting. Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

Comment: Well, if it works with SSH, it should work, unless the packages are dropped somewhere or not even routed correctly. on this case the problem is the path the package goes, firewall.. routers.. I am assuming the can route as SSH works.

Comment: In this case, I would double check the path for firewalls.. it might be even one on the campus or on the server. And the IPs both are using(But I guess u did that.). I don't think it is a java problem.

Comment: Those are two different computers in the SSH image. And yeah I'm going to contact the IT department and see if they might have an idea. I just checked the firewall and it seems like the exceptions are proper.

Comment: Updated the original post, it actually was a university issue.

Comment: Great. I was cracking my had that day.. please accept the answer if you see fit.